# Newbie Question: Modify forms before render

Tags: forms, media

I'm trying to style all the text inputs with and text areas from the forms.

They are complex images so I probably will have to build a div wrapper in order to do this. There is anyway to replace all the

```
<input>...</input>
```

to something like

```
<div><input>...</input></div>
```

before rendering the content in a theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really wouldn't use jquery to wrap form elements renderend by Drupal. What if the user has javascript disabled ?

Drupal provides several core api functions for theming forms, one of those is
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7

place the function in the template.php file of your custom theme (change the function name from 'theme_form_element' to 'mytheme_form_element'

change the contents of the function to your liking, especially look at places where there's html markup involved

Comment: Yup, I think I quite over engineered my solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to wrap every input of every form of your site, you can do this very easily client-side with jQuery [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

If you want to do this for some of your forms, you can use [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and the [`#prefix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix) and [`#suffix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) properties.

```php
$form['your_element']['#prefix'] = '<div class="new-class">';
$form['your_element']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

You can also try to traverse all elements of your `$form`, look out for the different elements you want wrap using [`#type`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#type) property. This could be a little more complicated as all elements can be included inside groups and be deeper in the form's array, but nothing a good recursive function wouldn't be able to resolve.